# Django reusable app testing - coveragerc

Tags: python, django, django-testing, coverage.py

I'm developing a Django reusable app. My development setup looks like this:

```
~/development/django-foo/
    foo/
        apps.py
        fixtures/
            ...
        forms/
            ...
        __init__.py
        models/
            ...
        static/
            foo/
                ...
        templates/
            foo/
                ...
        tests/
            ...
        urls.py
        views/
            ...
    .gitignore
    README.rst

~/virtualenv/foo/
    ...
    project_root/
        apps/
            __init__.py
            foo -> ~/development/django-foo/foo/
        manage.py
        project/
            __init__.py
            settings/
            urls.py
            wsgi.py
        static/
        templates/
```

I want to include a `.coveragerc` which contains specific settings for my app, like special `exclude_lines` (described [here](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/config.html#config)). Obviously, this should be specific for my app, so I'd like to place that file in `~/development/django-foo/.coveragerc`.
Anyway, `coverage` is installed inside the virtualenv and the *standard* call would be

```
(foo) ~/virtualenv/foo/ % coverage run --source='apps/foo' manage.py test foo && coverage report
```

As stated, I want to make use of a `.coveragerc`, according to the [docs](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/config.html),

> The default name for configuration files is .coveragerc, in the same directory coverage.py is being run in.

I would like `coverage` to look for that config file in another location or even better, find it on its own depending on the tested app.

Is there any common approach or should I write my own test-runner with coverage integration?

And yes, the idea of symlinking `~/virtualenv/foo/project_root/.coveragerc` to `~/development/django-foo/.coveragerc` already came to my mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, more reading would have prevented this question:

```
coverage help run
...
--rcfile=RCFILE       Specify configuration file.  Defaults to '.coveragerc'
```

I would still like to leave this open for other answers, especially regarding automatic discovery of app specific configuration files.